# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension (stock_quote gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting a strange error when trying to add the `stock_quote` gem to my gemfile.

The error is:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.5/ext/unf_ext
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180611-2823-17z0ly6.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... no
creating Makefile

current directory:
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.5/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.5/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [unf.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/cabox/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  stock_quote was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
    rest-client was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      http-cookie was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
        domain_name was resolved to 0.5.20180417, which depends on
          unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
            unf_ext
```

After seeing that, I tried to install `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.5` on it's own but received a similar error.

I found posts with a *similar* error, but I was unable to resolve it by following those.

Perhaps the issue is that I am using a [CodeAnywhere Firehose box](http://blog.thefirehoseproject.com/posts/setting-codeanywhere-development-environment/)

Other than that, I am not too sure what it could be. If you would like to see my repo please let me know or if more information is needed let me know.

Comment: You are missing some build tools notably g++.

Comment: Hey Joe, is there some documentation on how to add the missing build tools? I am not familiar with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ compiler is not installed on your system. If you're using Ubuntu run the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Normally I install several other packages which might be helpful during software development.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I was unable to run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` on the Codeanywhere but I ran `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -` first. I also ran `sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make`